# How to create a language button for tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a Python program in which I am using tkinter. What I would like is to have a button, with which I could change the language of other buttons/labels etc. throughout the whole program.

Upon restart it doesn't have to be able to save the preference, although if there's a way then I would love to have it save it. Maybe it would append an .txt document and upon opening check it to see what language was used etc. Could please someone tell me how to do that?

```
import hashlib
import requests
from tkinter import *
import os
import sys
import string
import random

root = Tk()
# root.config(bg="red")
root.option_add('*Font', 'Arial')
root.state("zoomed")
root.bind("<F11>", lambda event: root.attributes("-fullscreen", not root.attributes("-fullscreen")))
root.bind("<Escape>", lambda event: root.attributes("-fullscreen", False))


def restart():
    python = sys.executable
    os.execl(python, python, * sys.argv)


def invalid_password():
    error_password = Label(root, text="\n\nPlease enter a valid password")
    error_password.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
    restart_button = Button(root, text="Try another password", command=restart)
    restart_button.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
    root.bind('<Return>', lambda event=None: restart_button.invoke())


def error():
    error_message = Label(root, text="\n\nThere happened some kind of error, please try again")
    error_message.pack(padx=5, pady=5)


def compute(password):
    encoded_str = password.encode()
    hash_obj = hashlib.sha1(encoded_str)
    hashed = hash_obj.hexdigest().upper()
    beginning = hashed[:5]
    ending = hashed[5:].strip()
    response = requests.get("https://api.pwnedpasswords.com/range/" + beginning)
    output = response.text
    listing = output.split()
    return listing, ending


def feedback(password, listing, ending):
    compute(password)
    for line in listing:
        if ending in line:
            num = line.split(':')[1]
            warning_label = Label(root, text="\n\nYour password is not safe.\n"
                                             "It is found to have been part of " + num +
                                             " breaches! Change it now!")
            warning_label.pack(pady=5)
            restart_button = Button(root, text="Try another password", command=restart)
            restart_button.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
            root.bind('<Return>', lambda event=None: restart_button.invoke())
            suggest_button_random = Button(root,
                                           text="Suggest a safe password of random characters. It will automatically"
                                                " be copied to your clipboard!", command=alfa_suggest)
            suggest_button_random.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
            suggest_button_word = Button(root, text="Suggest a safe password of random words. It will automatically"
                                                    " be copied to your clipboard!", command=beta_suggest)
            suggest_button_word.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
            break
    else:
        congratulating_label = Label(root, text="\n\nYour password seems to be safe")
        congratulating_label.pack(pady=5)
        restart_button = Button(root, text="Try another password", command=restart)
        restart_button.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
        root.bind('<Return>', lambda event=None: restart_button.invoke())


def alfa_suggest():
    chosen_option = 1
    check_suggest(chosen_option)


def beta_suggest():
    chosen_option = 2
    check_suggest(chosen_option)


def suggest_random():
    p1 = "."
    p2 = ","
    p3 = "-"
    p4 = "_"
    p5 = "*"
    p6 = "!"
    p7 = "@"
    p8 = "£"
    p9 = "$"
    p10 = "="
    p11 = "?"
    suggestion = ''.join(random.SystemRandom().choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits + p1 + p2 + p3 + p4
                                                      + p5 + p6 + p7 + p8 + p9 + p10 + p11) for _ in range(15))
    password = suggestion
    return password


def check_suggest(chosen_option):
    if chosen_option == 1:
        password = suggest_random()
    else:
        a = random.randint(1, 2)
        if a == 1:
            first = random.choice(open('lowercase.txt').readlines()).strip()
        else:
            first = random.choice(open('uppercase.txt').readlines()).strip()
        a = random.randint(2, 3)
        if a == 2:
            second = random.choice(open('lowercase.txt').readlines()).strip()
        else:
            second = random.choice(open('uppercase.txt').readlines()).strip()
        password = first + "_" + second
    listing, ending = compute(password)
    for line in listing:
        if ending in line:
            check_suggest(chosen_option)
            break
    else:
        password_suggestion = Label(root, text=password)
        password_suggestion.pack(padx=10, pady=5)
        command = 'echo ' + password.strip() + '| clip'
        os.system(command)


def confirm_password_and_compute():
    password = e.get()
    intro.destroy()
    e.destroy()
    confirm_password_button.destroy()
    if password == "" or password.isspace():
        invalid_password()
    else:
        listing, ending = compute(password)
        feedback(password, listing, ending)


intro = Label(root, text="\n\nThis program checks for pwned passwords!\n"
                         "To check your current password against leaks, enter it here:")
intro.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
e = Entry(root, width=40)
e.pack()
confirm_password_button = Button(root, text="Confirm password", command=confirm_password_and_compute)
confirm_password_button.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
root.bind('<Return>', lambda event=None: confirm_password_button.invoke())


root.mainloop()
```

Pretty messy but here it is nevertheless

Comment: A *really* good way to do something like this would be via the [`gettext`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html) module in the standard library. ***However*** the code you have posted is inappropriate for asking a question like this here  — what is need so a [mre], not your while existing application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A .txt file would be very useful.
I would try creating one and then writing to it something like:

line = 'Good Morning !?!?! Bonjour'

Where `!?!?!` or any other seperator element would be your seperator. This way getting the text 'Good Morning' in French would be done like this:

```
text_in_french = line.split('!?!?!')[1]
```

Another way would be using a dictionary

```
dict = {'English': 'Good Morning', 'French': 'Bonjour'}
```

Then getting the text in any language would be pretty simple:

```
text_in_french = dict['French']
```

Let me know if you need further help

Comment: This is really a horrible way to do things... You should use standard methods like gettext...